# False Acceptance Rate and False Rejection Rate calculation using a n*n confusion matrix

Tags: weka, data-mining, biometrics, confusion-matrix

FAR and FRR are used to express the results of biometric devices. Below is the confusion matrix produced by biometric data produced in weka. I couldn't find any resources explaining the procedure to calculate FAR and FRR using a n*n confusion matrix. Any help explaining the procedure would be of great help. Thanks in advance!

Weka also gives these values, TP Rate, FP Rate, Precision, Recall, F-Measure and ROC Area. Please suggest if the required values can be calculated using these.

=== Confusion Matrix ===

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o   <-- classified as
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 | a = user1
 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 | b = user2
 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | c = user3
 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | d = user4
 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | e = user5
 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | f = user6
 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | g = user7
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | h = user9
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 | i = user10
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 | j = user11
 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | k = user14
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 | l = user15
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 | m = user16
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 | n = user17
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 | o = user19
```

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer here by user "chl"  has a reference to the Biometrics Literature: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3489/calculating-false-acceptance-rate-for-a-gaussian-distribution-of-scores .

He says,

> [the ROC curve] is a plot of   (TAR=1-FRR, the false rejection rate) against false
>   acceptance rate (FAR).

However, commonly the ROC curve happens to be a plot of TP Rate as a function of False Positive Rate (FP Rate).
Seems you can use TP Rate and FP Rate.